# Error regions in a simplistic measurement

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements

Suppose I measure two certain parameters, $a$ and $b$, in an object $O$ for two instances. My measurements are

Instance 1----> $a=1.4$, $b=1.4$

Instance 2---->$a=1.5$, $b=1.4$

Can, I say, hence for the object $O$,

$a=1.45\pm0.05$, $b=1.4$

This does not look right, since I did not improvise a measurement to the second decimal place. Hence now my measurement seems to be, precise to the second decimal place in case of the first parameter $a$ and to the first decimal place in case of the second parameter. How can I get my head around this?? Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

If you take measurement of a and b at two instances at identical condition then your answer a=1.45 or 1.4±0.1 is correct or there is change conditions then both of 1.4 and 1.5 may be correct. But i cannot get a=1.45±.01?